# Why does the CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation appear far from the plot symbol

Tags: ios, annotations, core-plot, symbols

I made annotations appear when clicking on the plot symbols using `plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex`, but for some plot symbols they appear very far and for some near the symbol, like it should. For example when clicking on the minimum point in the graph, the `CTPPlotSpaceAnnotiation` appears at the left side of the screen, not near the point.

EDIT: I figured what the problem is. NSNumber x gets no value, because the variable dates is a NSString and I think that it must be converted to NSDate and then to NSNumber. Should I get the number of months from the variables dates?, in order to use it in the variable anchor point, so that the annotation will show up near the plot symbol.

Another EDIT: Like I said above, I converted the NSString dates into NSDate and then into NSNumber and when I debug now, it shows me the number of days I think. But now when I click on the plot symbol, the annotation doesn't appear any more.
For example if the date is 07.2010, then x gets the value 299624400.0 and the annotation isn't working any more.

This is the code:

```
-(void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ( symbolTextAnnotation ) {
        [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea removeAnnotation:symbolTextAnnotation];
        symbolTextAnnotation = nil;
    }

    // Setup a style for the annotation
    CPTMutableTextStyle *hitAnnotationTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.color    = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";

    // Determine point of symbol in plot coordinates
    NSNumber *x          = [[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance].dates objectAtIndex:index];
    NSNumber *y          = [[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance].prices objectAtIndex:index];
    NSArray *anchorPoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, nil];

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    NSString *currentValue = [formatter stringFromNumber:[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance].prices objectAtIndex:index]];
    currentValue = [currentValue stringByAppendingString:@"-"];

    NSString *currentValue1 = [[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance].dates objectAtIndex:index];

    // Now add the annotation to the plot area
    CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:[currentValue stringByAppendingString:currentValue1] style:hitAnnotationTextStyle];
    symbolTextAnnotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace anchorPlotPoint:anchorPoint];
    symbolTextAnnotation.contentLayer = textLayer;
    symbolTextAnnotation.displacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 10.0f);
    [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea addAnnotation:symbolTextAnnotation];

}
```

This is the code for the plot, x-axis and y-axis:
-(void)configurePlots {

```
// 1 - Get graph and plot space
graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
// 2 - Create the three plots

aaplPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
aaplPlot.dataSource = self;

aaplPlot.delegate = self;
aaplPlot.plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection = 20.0f;

aaplPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolAAPL;
CPTColor *aaplColor = [CPTColor redColor];
[graph addPlot:aaplPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

msftPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
msftPlot.dataSource = self;
msftPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolMSFT;
CPTColor *msftColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
[graph addPlot:msftPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
// 3 - Set up plot space

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:aaplPlot, msftPlot, nil];
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:array];

CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)];
plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
[yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.2f)];
plotSpace.yRange = yRange;

// 4 - Create styles and symbols
CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplLineStyle = [aaplPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
aaplLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
aaplLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
aaplPlot.dataLineStyle = aaplLineStyle;
CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
aaplSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
CPTPlotSymbol *aaplSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
aaplSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:aaplColor];
aaplSymbol.lineStyle = aaplSymbolLineStyle;
aaplSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
aaplPlot.plotSymbol = aaplSymbol;

}

-(void)configureAxes {

// 1 - Create styles
CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
axisTextStyle.fontSize = 11.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
// 2 - Get axis set
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
// 3 - Configure x-axis
CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.title = @"Ziua Lunii";
x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
x.titleOffset = 15.0f;
x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
x.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
CGFloat dateCount = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth] count];
NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
NSInteger i = 0;

for (NSString *date in [[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth]) {
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:date textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    label.rotation = M_PI/4;
    CGFloat location = i++;
    label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
    label.offset = x.majorTickLength;
    if (label) {
        [xLabels addObject:label];
        [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
    }
}
x.axisLabels = xLabels;
x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;
// 4 - Configure y-axis
CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.title = @"Pret";
y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
y.titleOffset = -50.0f;
y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
y.labelOffset = 23.0f;
y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
NSInteger majorIncrement = 100;
NSInteger minorIncrement = 50;
CGFloat yMax = 1300.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableSet *yMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
for (NSInteger j = minorIncrement; j <= yMax; j += minorIncrement) {
    NSUInteger mod = j % majorIncrement;
    if (mod == 0) {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
        NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j);
        label.tickLocation = location;
        label.offset = - y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;
        if (label) {
            [yLabels addObject:label];
        }
        [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
    } else {
        [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];
    }
}
y.axisLabels = yLabels;
y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
y.minorTickLocations = yMinorLocations;

}
```

Comment: The correct conversion depends on how the x-axis is scaled. How does the datasource compute the correct x-values?

Comment: @EricSkroch I updated my question with your request.

Comment: @EricSkroch maybe you can figure out why the annotation appears left on the screen of the iPhone and not near the plotSymbol I click on. I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the data index for x-values. This is easy; no need to convert the date at all:

```
NSNumber *x = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
```

Comment: Eric you are my life saver. I struggled so many days. Thank you very very much.:)